# Identifying line breaks anywhere in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for ways in which I can run an equivalent of a 'find' in Python in order to be able to identify line breaks.

I have tried using this but it didn't return any results unexpectedly:

```
df[df.isin(['\n']).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `str` accessor has a [function to search for substrings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

```
df["colA"].str.contains(r"\n")
```

Use it in conjunction with `apply` to get your solution.

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r"\n"))
```

Comment: Hi thanks.  I found this to be the closest to what I need.  I did not realize that I would get a lot of noise with 'NaN' though.  is there a way I can trim the results from df.apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(r"\n")) that would remove all rows or all columns where the contains condition is not met (False or NaN)?  Appreciated.

Comment: Use `.fillna` to replace the NaN values with an empty string, and then use `.any` or `.all` (like you have done in your question) to filter rows/columns depending on your specific condition

Answer (score 0):

If you want a **pd.DataFrame** as result, use:

```
df1 = testdf[testdf['B'].str.contains('\n')]
```

Another solution would be with **iloc** and **np.where**:

```
testdf.iloc[np.where(testdf['B'].str.contains('\n', regex=False))]
```